# Netbeans - The specific folder does not contain JDK

Tags: netbeans

I hope you are doing well and for those that are in the USA, that you are staying safe!

I have just got a new laptop and have downloaded Netbeans, however, when I try setting it up, it says, as the title suggests " The specific folder does not contain JDK". I do not know what to as the location clearly has JDK 11.0.2 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2) in it! I have also tried C:\Program Files\Java but that doesn't have much luck either. Any ideas what I have to do? I have looked at other websites to see if they had a suggestion but none of those were successful.

Cheers!

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using? The only version of NetBeans which supports JDK 11 is [Apache NetBeans 10.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html), so a possible cause of your problem is that you are using an older version of NetBeans. Alternatively, if you are using NetBeans 8.x you can use JDK 8 instead, or if you are using NetBEans 9.0 you can use JDK8 or JDK 9 or JDK 10 instead.

Comment: Thanks, it all works now!